# Automatic display of buttons of opening disk partitions

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm doing a file manager. It is necessary that when the program was launched, the buttons with the selection of an existing disk partition were displayed. At the moment, everything happens according to the code below. Simply, there are four buttons with a "C", "D", "E", "F", but suddenly the user has only "C", then there should only be a "C" button.

```
private void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.Navigate(@"C:\");
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hiding / displaying buttons under certain conditions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43384653/hiding-displaying-buttons-under-certain-conditions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in the following way:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace DemoApplication
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // We need to get all logic drives of the system on Forms load
            var localDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
            int i = 0;
            foreach(DriveInfo localDrive in localDrives)
            {
                // Create for each Drive the specific button
                Button bt = new Button();
                // Add specific text to button
                bt.Text = localDrive.Name;
                // Set button's width
                bt.Width = 40;
                // Set location
                bt.Location =  new Point(10+40*i,10);
                i++;
                // Add event handler for click to open File Explorer for that drive
                bt.Click += new EventHandler((obj, args) =>
                {
                    // This will open File explorer to the given path
                    Process.Start(localDrive.RootDirectory.FullName);
                });
                // And finally add our button to the Form
                this.Controls.Add(bt);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

More information about System.IO.DriveInfo you can find [DriveInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.getdrives(v=vs.110).aspx)

More information about System.Diagnostics.Process.Start you can find [Process.Start](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I do not understand this. Why Console.WriteLine? Buttons for the transfer to the disk partition which is not on the PC should be hidden. But the buttons to go to the disk partition that are on the PC must be on the form.

Comment: @River it's just example how to get System Logic Drives in the Console Application. You need to get the selection of drives and show buttons.

Comment: Can you help me with this? I do not understand how to write this code.

Comment: @River ok, I will update my answer to WinForm Solution

Comment: Works! Only there are a few nuances. 1 - It is necessary that the buttons do not open the win explorer, they should display the disk partition in the webBrowser1 component. 2 - Buttons should be created on panel2. 3 - These buttons should be with certain appearance options and must have a Dock property. Can somehow set these parameters at once?

Comment: In any case, thanks for the help. You helped me a lot. Sorry, I can not put my voice up for an answer, my reputation is small.