# Hiding / displaying buttons under certain conditions

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

On the `form1` there are `buttons` with this code. There is a `button` to go to the disk partition "C", "D", "E", "F" and so on. If the computer has such a disk partition - the `button` is visible else the `button` is hidden. How to do it?

```
private void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.Navigate(@"C:\");
        }
```

Comment: Are you looking on how to make a button invisible or do you want to know how to check if it needs to be invisible?

Comment: All buttons are hidden by default. But the button should be displayed if there is a disk partition that it can open.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the follwoing code on your `Page_Load()`

```
foreach (System.IO.DriveInfo item in System.IO.DriveInfo.GetDrives())
{
    if(item.Name == "C:\\")
    {
        button10.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        button10.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This code is inserted into Form1_load? And do I need to finish something or will it work right away?

Comment: This is for just one button you will need to add more if conditions to let the code handle the rest of the controls. Other than that this should work just fine.

Comment: I understand it. But I don't understand where exactly to insert this code?

Comment: Code is to be inserted at Form_Load()

Comment: So as soon as the form loads it will only display those buttons which exist as drives in your system

Comment: I asked because it does not work. The disk partition "C" is, but the button is always hidden.

Comment: Have you tried debugging it? because it seems to work just fine at my end. You also try keeping all buttons visibility true in the designer and let the code change it's visibility. I hope that should help.

Comment: Just a query are these buttons of yours on the form or are they inside a panel which has it's visibility set to false?

Comment: Buttons on the panel that is visible

Comment: Check the visibility of the panel or any other parent containers involved. Because if their visibility is set false then the button's visibility wouldn't change irrespective of the code it runs through. Debugger will help you best.

Comment: I created a new project to check. The button that opens the section "C" is always hidden, regardless of whether there is such a section or not.

Comment: I am really not sure how to help you then. The code is working fine on my PC. Are you sure you're using those double backward slash?

Comment: It's got something to do with the panel itself it's embedded in.

Answer (score 0):

You can use visibility property of a button in this kind of scenario.
for example:

```
if(condition) {
button.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: You can use this button.Visible = condition;

Answer (score 0):

`button10_Click()` this is a button event of your Form, inside that you can write like this

```
if(System.IO.DriveInfo.Contains == yourDrive)
{
    button10.visible = true;
}
else 
{
    button10.visible = false;
}
```

Comment: Just wondering how will the user click on a button which is invisible to start with?

Answer (score 0):

Well since your buttons are hidden by default, you can write a 
`refresh()` method. Inside you can ask if a specific drive exists.

```
string drive = @"C:\";
if (Directory.Exists(drive))
{
   button.Visible = true;
}
```

---

> Where do I add that code?

You should add the method call or code at a place that will:

- be called everytime the Form/Control/Site is refreshed or intialized. Maybe in your `Form1.Load` Event.
- when the buttons get initialized or they need to be seen.

A example for maybe a method you can use:

```
private void CheckForDisks()
{
  if (Directory.Exists(@"C:\"))
  {
    buttonC.Visible = true;
  }
  if (Directory.Exists(@"D:\"))
  {
    buttonD.Visible = true;
  }
  if (Directory.Exists(@"E:\"))
  {
    buttonE.Visible = true;
  }
  // and so on... you can also do this with a loop, look up Adarsh Ravi answer for this
}
```

You can call this method either in your `Form1.Load` event like:

```
privat void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  this.CheckForDisks();
}
```

Comment: Can be more? Where do I insert code and what should I add?

Comment: @Eve Did it worked out for you? Let us know so developer with similar problems can find the answer fast, or If it doesn't work, we could find another way to solve it.